# Imprimir una matriz con tkinter en python

Tags: python, interfaz

Quisiera saber si hay alguna función que me imprima varias filas de una matriz usando la interfaz tkinter en python.
Estoy tratando de imprimir una y solo me muestra la primera fila de 5.
Mientras que si lo corro por consola, me muestra toda la matriz

Esta es una parte del código

```
 # ACÁ DECLARO LA VARIABLE
 Resultado = tk.StringVar()

    label_resultado = tk.Label(ventana, text="Resultado",bg="light slate blue", fg="black")
    label_resultado.place(y=100, x=40)


    resultadoTxt = tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable = Resultado, state= tk.DISABLED)
    resultadoTxt.place(y=100, x =160, height= 80, width=170)

#Y ASÍ ES COMO LA IMPLENETO EN MI MÉTODO
Resultado.set(etapaBase)
```

Comment: Hola Fabio, agrega el código o al menos un [mcve] si no va a ser complicado ayudar. No sabemos ni el widget que usas ni como intentas mostrar la lista en el.... Usa el botón editar que haay debajo de tu pregunta y aagregaa lo necesario a ella. Un saludo.

Comment: Fabio usa el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/346759/edit) y agrega el código a la pregunta, los comentarios además de tener limitado el espacio no permiten formatear código, perdemos el identado y el identado en Python es primordial.

Comment: Ahora si, ya edité la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

```
   #Usa grid!!
    def most():
        print(r[0])
        e=r[0]
        root = Tk()
        root.title("matriz A")
        root.config(bg="black")
        for g in range(len(e)):
            for c in range(len(e[g])):
                cell = Entry(root, width=10)
                cell.grid(row=g, column=c)
                cell.insert(0, '{}'.format(e[g][c]))
        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Considera agregar una explicación a tu código, checa [answer]